# Google Maps Geocoding API request issue in Android Studio with okHTTP

Tags: android, android-studio, google-geocoding-api

I am trying to get JSON from Google Maps Geocoding API using okHTTP (http://square.github.io/okhttp/) in Android Studio and my program crashes with the following error log:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4020)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
        at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:184)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:153)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:95)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:345)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:328)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:246)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:276)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:234)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:196)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:79)
                                ...
```

The last error log's `Caused by` gives a hint that the issue might be in okHTTP security communication. I did not set it up because I can not figure out whether I need to do it at all and how to do it then. This page might be relevant, but I am not sure: https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/HTTPS

Communication with Google Geocoding API happens through `https`.

Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
String strAddress = "Winnetka";
    String googleMapsAPIKey = this.getString(R.string.google_maps_api_key);
    String url = null;
    try {
        url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json" +
                "?address=" + URLEncoder.encode(strAddress, "UTF-8") + "&key=" + googleMapsAPIKey;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();
    try {
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
```

It fails on the line `Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();`

I logged out the url that I formed and it looks identical to the one that is used in the examples on the API's website (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro):

```
 https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Winnetka&key=...
```

Could anyone, please, help?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue: `Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

You should use OkHttps async method:

```
client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
  @Override 
  public void onFailure(Request request, IOException throwable) {
    throwable.printStackTrace();
  }

  @Override 
  public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
      if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
          throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
      }

      // Do Stuff
});
```

Comment: I tried it but the request still fails with the error: `W/System.err﹕ java.io.IOException: stream was reset: PROTOCOL_ERROR` in blue color.  It goes to `public void onFailure(Request request, IOException throwable)` method.

Comment: Is there any `OkHttpsClient`? It seems not present in the API, so I am using just `OkHttpClient`.

Comment: I guess, it is this issue: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1195. I am thinking of trying http://loopj.com/android-async-http/   instead of okHttp...

Comment: @NikitaVlasenko It could be that or it could be [this](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1844). The closing comment suggests its an issue server side and not with the library.

Comment: So, you mean that it might be google API's Geocoding issue and I would need to use some other API? That's strange.

Comment: @NikitaVlasenko I'm just reiterating the conclusion the OkHttp authors reached. Try out a different library, it could just as well be a bug in OkHttp. Are you using the latest version?

Comment: Android-async-http is compatible with Android SDK 23, but I am using SDK 22, so it is not the right choice, I guess.